# Add physicsbody to node in spritekit editor

Tags: xcode6, sprite-kit

In spritekit editor of xcode 6.3.1, I can't find the way to add a physicsbody to a node, since physicsbody is a property of node, it makes no sense? So, somebody can tell me how. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using code to add a physics body?

Comment: Yes, code is ok. But I have a lot of nodes in my scene which just have physics body without image, if I can use the spritekit editor, that will reduce lots of works.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method to create generic SKSpriteNodes and return them.

```
-(SKSpriteNode *)createInvisibleNodeWithSize:(CGSize)nodeSize {
    SKSpriteNode *myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:nodeSize];
    myNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
    // set up rest of physics body properties

    return myNode;
}

-(void)myMethod {
    SKSpriteNode *someNode = [self createInvisibleNodeWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [self addChild:someNode];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I can add node from code. But since I have hundreds of invisible nodes in different position, if I can edit in the scene editor and load the sks file in the code, then I can using one line code to add them to the scene. Now, I just add a transparent image as a sprite's texture, but this is weird, since the physics body is a property of node, why I can't edit it in spritekit editor, but for a sprite, I can, so I wondering maybe I didn't got the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using scene editor and you already have some sprite in it.

To add physics body, you need to follow this way:

1. Select you node
2. Open the "Utilities" panel (the right panel in Xcode)
3. Open "Attributes Inspector" in it (3rd option)
4. Choose "Physics Definition" section -> "Body type"
   You have 3 options here:

   - Bounding rectangle
   - Bounding circle
   - Alpha mask
5. Choose necessary type. In most cases you will need "Bounding rectangle" or "Bounding circle".
6. Fill additional physics properties (like friction, restitution etc). These props will be available after selecting "Body Type" option.

[image: Screenshot]